# What's controller's job if using MVC model in node.js

Tags: node.js

This is what i'm thinking,

```
const myController (req, res) => {
    verify_input(req);

    try {
        myService(req);
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

What are the things to improve pls ?

Comment: Seems good enough. What do you want to improve ? Controller stands for the logic of your application, as you do in your sample code.

Comment: @TGrif i'm not familiar with MVC, want to know what's supposed to do in controller, what's not. In the past i just write straight node code, until ppl suggested MVC.